How does Ettus X310 sampling rate work?
Today I am reading the specification of X310 and I have come across several questions regarding how it samples from the RF signal at RX Antenna down to the baseband IQ samples.
So, an USRP device has two stages of tuning:

RF front-end: translates between RF and IF
DSP: translates between IF and baseband

At stage 1, the daughter board (UBX-160 in my case) will choose a LO frequency that is closest to the desired center frequency and mix with it to down convert it to an IF.
Then, this IF passband is fed into the ADC with a sampling rate of the fraction-N of either the following master clock rates:

200 MHz (by default)
184.32 MHz

(Fractional-N here means the the sampling rate must be a multiple of the master clock rate, like 2* 100 MHz sampling rate = 200 MHz master clock rate is allowable)
The IF passband, now being digitally sampled, is further shifted to baseband by mixing it with $e^{i2\pi f_{\text{dif}}t}$, where $f_{\text{dif}} =  f_{\text{lower bound}} -f_{\text{LO}}$ ($f_{\text{lower bound}}$ is referred to as $f_{\text{low}}$ in the three figures below). After that, this baseband signal is passed to FPGA for further processing like FFT etc.



Now, my question is:

How is the local oscillator frequency chosen by the X310? If LO frequency is same as the lower bound of the target signal, i.e. $f_{\text{lower bound}}$, then the signal is directly down converted to baseband which is good. Is X310 able to do so, saving the IF to baseband conversion?
What is the actual signal bandwidth offered by X310? From figure 2 we can see that the signal is not at baseband and so the actual signal bandwidth must be smaller than the 200 MHz offered by the sampling rate. Also we need to save some bandwidth for anti-aliasing.

Please point out any mistakes I have made since I am very new to DSP. Thank you.


DSP: translates between IF and baseband

ah, no. These are baseband-sampling ("IQ") devices. The RF frontends (the "daughterboards" already convert to baseband.

At stage 1, the daughter board (UBX-160 in my case) will choose a LO

No, that happens in the UHD driver on your PC

frequency that is closest to the desired center frequency and mix with it to down convert it to an IF.

No, that will not be an IF, but 0 Hz, by default, unless you specify it not to be.

Then, this IF passband is fed into the ADC with a sampling rate of the fraction-N of either the following master clock rates:

No, nothing is "fractional-N" in the sampling path. A fractional-N synthesizer might be on your daughterboard to produce the LO, but not to feed the ADC on the motherboard with a sample clock.
No, the ADC doesn't run with a derived as a fraction of the master clock rate, it runs exactly at the master clock rate.
What is correct to say is that the FPGA can downsample your 200 MHz signal to a range of integer factors of 200 MHz: 100 MHz, 200/3 MHz, 50 MHz, 40 MHz, 200/6 MHz, 200/7 MHz, 25 MHz… (same for the 184.32 MHz rate, but it's not common you'd use anything but the cellular-standards-related 31.72 MHz times 1, 2 or 4).

(Fractional-N here means the the sampling rate must be a multiple of the master clock rate, like 2* 100 MHz sampling rate = 200 MHz master clock rate is allowable)

That is not what fractional-N means. It's kind of the opposite!

How is the local oscillator frequency chosen by the X310?

Not at all by the X310. That happens in your host computer, in the driver, which tries to find the closest frequency that the LO synthesizer on the individual daughterboard (there's many different daughterboards!) can synthesiize.

What is the actual signal bandwidth offered by X310?

With a 200 MS/s sampling rate, you can represent at most a bandwidth 200 MHz.
The actual analog frontend bandwidth is defined by the daugherboard; there's daughterboards with many different bandwidths; the wider ones do 160 MHz, some do 120 MHz, others 80 MHz or 40 MHz.

Hello thank you for your detailed reply. I would like to ask some follow up questions.

Referring to this post, f_target in uhd.tune_request(f_target, f_offset) is the LO chosen by UHD, then what is f_offset? I thought there is an IF stage and hence f_offset is needed to further bring it down to baseband.
So the analogue frontend bandwidth (160 MHZ for UBX) is smaller than the sampling bandwidth (i.e. 200 MHz), which is due to anti-aliasing guard band reserved etc?



It's the difference to the target frequency, which you request. in that post I explain that pretty detailledly. Feel free to post a new question post that explains what you didn't understand about my answer there! 2. yes, 160 MHz < 200 MHz.

